# Convert a single column into multiple columns based on delimiter in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, reshape

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID Parts
-- -----
1  A:B::
2  X2:::
3  ::J4:
4  A:C:D:G4:X6
```

And I would like the convert the Parts column into multiple columns by the `:` delimiter. so it should look like:

```
ID A  B  X2  J4  C  D  G4  X6 ........
-- -  -  --  --  -  -  --  -- 
1  A  B  na  na  na na na  na
2  na na X2  na  na na na  na
3  na na na  J4  na na na  na
4  A  na na  na  C  D  G4  X6
```

where there I would not know the number of potential columns in advance.

I have met my match on this one - strsplit() by delim I can do but only with fixed number of entities in the `Parts` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `tidyr::seperate`, `tidyr::pivot_wider`, and `tidyr::pivot_longer`. First you can still use `strsplit` to determine the number of **columns** to split `Parts` into *not* the number of unique values (**How it works**):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

n_col <- max(stringr::str_count(df$Parts, ":")) + 1

df %>% 
  tidyr::separate(Parts, into = paste0("col", 1:n_col), sep = ":") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(across(everything(), ~dplyr::na_if(., ""))) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-name) %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na() %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = ID,
                     names_from = value)


     ID A     B     X2    J4    C     D     G4    X6   
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A     B     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
2     2 NA    NA    X2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
3     3 NA    NA    NA    J4    NA    NA    NA    NA   
4     4 A     NA    NA    NA    C     D     G4    X6
```

---

**How it works**

You do not need to know the number of unique values with this code -- the pivots take care of that. What you do need to know is how many new columns `Parts` will be split into with `seperate`. That's easy to do by counting the number of delimiters and adding one with `str_count`. This way you have the appropriate number of columns to seperate `Parts` into by your delimiter.

This is because `pivot_longer` will create a two column dataframe with repeated `ID` and a column with the delimited values of `Parts` -- an `ID`, `Parts` pairing. Then when you use `pivot_wider` the columns are automatically created for each unique value of `Parts` and the value is retained within the column. This function automatically fills with `NA` where an `ID` and `Parts` combination is not found.

Try running this pipe by pipe to better understand if need be.

---

**Data**

```
lines <- "
ID Parts
1  A:B::
2  X2:::
3  ::J4:
4  A:C:D:G4:X6
"

df <- read.table(text = lines, header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks very much - that's some dplyr/tidyr chain and have learnt some tricks going through it.

Answer (score 0):

Could the `seperate` function from `tidyr` be what you are looking for?

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html

It might require some fancy regex implementation, but could potentially work.

Comment: At least I provided the right link... Thanks for the clarification!